# Cannot find modules on mongoose on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have an error on my heroku app which is **2019-08-03T10:56:56.753066+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './models/Marker' .**
I already saw a [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53944893/cannot-find-mongodb-module-when-deploying-to-heroku) on it but it does not work for me ( deleting the node_modules package does not work / adding node_modules to .gitignore)

My package.json :

```js
{
  "name": "node_passport_login",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Node.js authentication with Passport",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-ejs-layouts": "^2.5.0",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "mongodb": "^3.3.0-beta2",
    "mongoose": "^5.6.7",
    "overpass-frontend": "^2.4.3",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.2.0",
    "socketio": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.15.0"
  }
}
```

The line to require the model :

```js
const Marker = require('./models/Marker');
```

The whole error :

```sh
2019-08-04T11:27:42.587474+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command node app.js
2019-08-04T11:27:44.635440+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-08-04T11:27:44.616214+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-08-04T11:27:44.560379+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
2019-08-04T11:27:44.560407+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-08-04T11:27:44.560409+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-08-04T11:27:44.560410+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-08-04T11:27:44.560412+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './models/Marker'
2019-08-04T11:27:44.560416+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
2019-08-04T11:27:44.560418+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
2019-08-04T11:27:44.560422+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
2019-08-04T11:27:44.560424+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
2019-08-04T11:27:44.560425+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:7:16)
2019-08-04T11:27:44.560427+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
2019-08-04T11:27:44.560428+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
2019-08-04T11:27:44.560430+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
2019-08-04T11:27:44.560431+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
2019-08-04T11:27:44.560433+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
2019-08-04T11:27:44.560434+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
2019-08-04T11:27:44.560435+00:00 app[web.1]: at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
2019-08-04T11:27:44.560437+00:00 app[web.1]: at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

`heroku local web`works.

Edit: `./models/Marker` is the directory to a module export of a mongoose schema

Comment: What is `./models/Marker`?

Comment: @NinoFiliu It's the directory to a module export of a mongoose schema

Comment: "deleting the node_modules package does not work / adding node_modules to .gitignore"—you should *definitely* remove `node_modules/` from your repository if it's tracked. You can't just add it to `.gitignore`; it must be *removed*, e.g with something like `git rm -r --cached node_modules`, then committing and deploying again.

Comment: @Chris i did `git rm -r --cached node_modules` but it printed `fatal: pathspec 'node_modules' did not match any files`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that i am on windows so it is not case sensitive and my file was marker.js and not Marker.js so it was working on local but on linux, it needs to be exactly the same name

Comment: Thx, I had the same error, it looks like macOS is not case  sensitive as well